# Change route running

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created this route: Home / PaginaBase.
This route is called a new page, called *PaginaBase*, which has a similar header and footer Index. This creates a footer menu.
When I select an item from this menu, he calls me PaginaBase riding a URL like this:
http://www.localhost:58686/Home/PaginaBase/6/3. 
 Until then, it's ok. When I select another item (PaginaBase still inside), it retains the same URL in the call and adds `Home/PaginaBase/8/3` again, there is a non-existent route.
How do I solve this?

Below is my jquery function.

```
function MontaMenuInferior() {

    var str = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/MontaMenuInferior',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

            $(data.resultado).each(function () {

                str = str + '<ul class="grid_4">' +
                                    '<li>' + this.SubCategoria + '</li>';


                $(this.subconsulta).each(function () {

                    if (this.Id_SubCategoria2 != null) 

                        str = str + '<li><a href="Home/PaginaBase/' + this.Id_SubCategoria2 + '/3" title="">' + this.SubCategoria2 + '</a></li>';
                        //str = str + '<li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl(PaginaBase"',new{ Parametro : this.Id_SubCategoria2, tipo : '3'} + ")">this.SubCategoria2 + '</a>'
                    else
                        str = str + '<li><a href="#' + this.SubCategoria2 + '" title="">' + this.SubCategoria2 + '</a></li>';

                });

                str = str + '</ul>';

                $('#menufooter').append(str);

                str = "";

            });
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using relative URLs in your links. If you're in `/Home/PaginaBase/6/3` (i.e. that's your **path**) and you click a link to `Home/PaginaBase/8/3` your new path will be `/Home/PaginaBase/6/3/Home/PaginaBase/8/3`.

Using absolute URLs will **replace** your path instead of appending to it: `/Home/PaginaBase/8/3` (notice the `/` in the beginning).